# typedef of std::initializer_list instantiation

Tags: c++, typedef, initializer-list

A typedef of an instantiation of std::initializer_list does not behave the same as the instantiation itself. In the following code (compiled with gcc 4.4.6) a variable declared using the instantiation directly requires single parentheses for initialization, while a variable declared using the typedef requires double parentheses. (Oddly, the compiler gives an 'unused variable' warning for the former but not for the latter.) Also, the argument type can apparently be deduced for a function parameter declared with the instantiation, but not for a function parameter declared with the typedef.

```
struct S { int a; int b; };
template class std::initializer_list< S >;  // same results with or without this
typedef std::initializer_list< S >  SL;

void fs1( std::initializer_list< S > data ) {}
void fs2( SL data ) {}

int main()
{
    std::initializer_list< S > s11{ { 11, 22 }, { 33, 44 } };     // compiles w/ single parentheses
//  std::initializer_list< S > s12{{ { 11, 22 }, { 33, 44 } }};   // ERROR 1

//  SL s21{ { 55, 66 }, { 77, 88 } };     // ERROR 2
    SL s22{{ { 55, 66 }, { 77, 88 } }};   // compiles w/ double parentheses

    fs1( { { 11, 22 }, { 33, 44 } } );    // ok w/ no arg. type

//  fs2( { { 55, 66 }, { 77, 88 } } );    // ERROR 3
//  fs2( {{ { 55, 66 }, { 77, 88 } }} );  // ERROR 4
//  fs2( SL{ { 55, 66 }, { 77, 88 } } );  // ERROR 2
    fs2( SL{{ { 55, 66 }, { 77, 88 } }} );  // requires arg. type & double par. to compile
}

// ERROR 1: could not convert '{{{11, 22}, {33, 44}}}' to 'std::initializer_list<S>'
// ERROR 2: no matching function for call to 'std::initializer_list<S>::initializer_list(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
// ERROR 3: could not convert '{{55, 66}, {77, 88}}' to 'SL'
// ERROR 4: could not convert '{{{55, 66}, {77, 88}}}' to 'SL'
```

Why does the typedef'ed instantiation behave differently from the non-typedef'ed version? Is there a different syntax that would enable type deduction without specifying the argument type for the typedef'ed version?

BTW, I don't know if a type alias would exhibit the same difference in behavior, but it's not an option since I'm stuck with gcc 4.4.6 for now.

Comment: I don't see any evidence of the typedefed instantion behaving any differently than the non-typedefed version, here.

Comment: `initializer_list` is a C++11 feature. Does gcc 4.4.6 support the c++11 flag? 4.4.7 does not recognize it. https://godbolt.org/z/XhUQLh

Comment: @Sam, the evidence is that they require different syntaxes for variable initialization and for function calls in order to compile.

Comment: @P.W, yes, it supports the C++11 flag (which I have turned on), but only implements a subset of the C++11 features. That subset includes Initializer_list.

Comment: @user3065699: From the version (4.7.1) I can test online, even the typedef version `SL s22{{ { 55, 66 }, { 77, 88 } }};` does not compile with double parentheses. https://godbolt.org/z/hbRKlJ

Comment: @P.W, I don't know why that would be. It compiles for me. I have the  -std=c++0x and -Wall flags set and #include <initializer_list>.